# Symfony: trouble adding Prototype to view.yml

Tags: php, symfony1, prototypejs

I added the following to my view.yml

```
javascripts:    [%SF_PROTOTYPE_WEB_DIR%/js/prototype]
```

However, Symfony isn't including prototype properly.  When I look at the source code, I see this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/%SF_PROTOTYPE_WEB_DIR%/js/prototype.js"></script>
```

which I don't think is right.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have prototype.js in your /web/js folder, all you need is

```
javascripts:  [prototype]
```

Symfony cannot replace sf_prototype_web_dir, because you do not have a config setting named like that.

Comment: @Rain, you may be looking at example code from earlier versions of Symfony; I think Prototype was bundled in earlier versions, including the prototype_web_dir setting.